# How do you remove the title text from the Android ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm looking through the `Holo.Light` theme, and I can't seem to find the magic style to override to get rid of the title text that briefly shows up when my app first launches.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Got it. You have to override

```
android:actionBarStyle
```

and then in your custom style you have to override

```
android:titleTextStyle
```

Here's a sample.

In my themes.xml:

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

And in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="NoTitleText">
        <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

I'm not sure why setting the textSize to zero didn't do the trick (it shrunk the text, but didn't make it go away), but setting the textColor to transparent works.

Comment: Yes that helped. Any idea why `android:visibility=gone` has no effect? Or better yet, why does `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled` still show the title text while the bar is loading?

Comment: Use <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item> instead of setting size to 0

Answer (score 222):

Try:

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

For v.7:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: you will still see the title while the action bar is loading which is not what you want. the right solution is what m3n0R suggested.

Comment: it should be getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); for v7 . othewise it will produce null pointer execption

Comment: @numansalati Who is m3n0R? I've searched the page and found nothing

Comment: When should I cal the methods? I mean from which method (activity, fragment) should it be called?

Comment: You just need this once, in `onCreate` of your `MainActivity.tk`. This is the right solution, ignore the comments above.

Answer (score 96):

I think this is the right answer:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What about Android 4? I am not using ActionBarSherlock so there is no resource named `Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`. What parent should I use?

Comment: Holo Theme. By default there are 3 holo themes you can extend on.

Comment: This works for hiding the title on first launch. In another activity calling setTitle doesn't work. Is there a way to swap action bar styles at runtime?

Comment: setting the default theme on runtime :)

Comment: @domji84, You can specify the theme of each activity in the manifest file.

Comment: I had to set the `android:actionBarStyle` on the style of the `Activity`, not the `Application`. So, use `parent=@style/Theme.AppCompat` and apply to the Activity. Just a tip to others struggling to get this working.

Comment: For Android 4, you can extend from `Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`

Answer (score 63):

I'm very new to Android so correct me if I'm wrong, but I think if you decide to use navigation tabs on the Action Bar, they seemed to not be completely left aligned because the title text color is only transparent and hasn't gone away.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

worked for me.

Comment: yes,you are wrong, no tabs in question and no holo light in your answer

Comment: While am try this, am getting this error, @android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar requires API level 11 (current min is 10).

Comment: If I want to assign this style to action bar of a specific activity and not for all the activities of my application. How can I do it? where do I put the 'android:displayOptions' line? in Menu.xml? In AndroidMenifest.xml?

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Please add more details for a end-to-end solution.

Answer (score 24):

In your Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityHere"
     android:label="">
```

Comment: This does work, but will stop your app appearing in the 'Recently used apps' chooser

Comment: this make the app don't have name on phone applications / main screen

Comment: Hi @RupertBates, @Nimitack, it seems works if you assign your app name in the `application` tab, i.e., `<application
        android:label="your_app_name">...`

Answer (score 14):

Write this statement under

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

if  extending AppCompactActivity use **`getSupportActionbar()`** if extending Activity use **`getActionBar()`** else it may give

```
null pointer exception
```

using  `android:label=""` in `AndroidManifest.xml`  for activity also works but your app won't appear in `Recently used apps`

Answer (score 9):

you have two choice:

**first:**

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

If usign `getActionBar()` produced null pointer exception, you should use `getSupportActionBar()`

**Second**

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("your title");
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change the style applied to each activity, or if you only want to change the behavior for a specific activity, you can try this:

```
setDisplayOptions(int options, int mask) --- Set selected display 
  or
setDisplayOptions(int options) --- Set display options.
```

To display title on actionbar, set display options in onCreate()

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

To hide title on actionbar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions(int,%20int)).

Answer (score 6):

**i use this code in App manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo2"
        android:label="@string/title_text"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Zinoostyle" >
```

**my logo file is 200*800 pixel 
and use this code in main activity.java**

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

it will work Corectly

Answer (score 6):

I tried this. This will help -

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

getSupportActionBar should be called after setSupportActionBar, thus setting the toolbar, otherwise, NullpointerException because there is no toolbar set. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that really worked for me was to add:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".ActivityHere"
    android:label=""
>
```

Comment: well was the "wrong" answer,however it help me with a similar case :)

Comment: Don't do this as it will crash your application when minimized

Answer (score 3):

as a workaround just add this line incase you have custom action/toolbars

```
this.setTitle("");
```

in your Activity

Answer (score 3):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to do it for one activity and perhaps even dynamically, you can also use

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions() ^ ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: You can't do that if you're using the ActionBar. If you try to do this the app will immediately crash when it opens.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry not true. you can use this to remove the action bar in code, provided you do it before calling setContentView.

Comment: though, this is removing the whole actionbar instead of just its title!

Answer (score 1):

While all of these are acceptable, if your activity only contains a main activity, you can edit `res\values\styles.xml` like so:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've updated `parent` and added the .NoActionBar property to the Light theme from Android Studios `Create Blank Application` Wizard.

Comment: That will disable entire action bar not only title. And if you want to create blank action bar you will have to do it for every single view.

Answer (score 1):

Simply extends your java file from `AppCompatActivity` and do this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // support.v7
actionBar.setTitle(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.xml page you can give address to your activity label. the address is somewhere in your values/strings.xml . then you can change the value of the tag in xml file to null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title_main_activity"></string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Android so maybe I am wrong...but to solve this problem cant we just go to the manifest and remove the activity label

```
<activity
        android:name=".Bcft"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        **android:label="" >**
```

Worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

I remove the default appbar and run a custom toolbar instead using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` then add a textview or something that extend to full toolbar width using attribute `layout_width=match_parent` and it pushes the title out of the toolbar. If you want to do this, you must study how to make a toolbar.

Answer (score -3):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("");
```

Comment: @Matteo Although it may work, it's certainly sketchy and not the right way to do it. In fact, it doesn't actually remove the title text, it just sets it to "", so that you cannot see it.