# Remove the title text from the action bar in one single activity

Tags: android

I added an action bar with a dropdown menu to my activity but it also shows the application name.

Each of my activities has an action bar and each of them use the theme `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`. One one my activity screens I would like to display the action bar with the dropdown/spinner menu but I would like to hide the application title.

I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7656019/304151) on another SO post but it required me changing the global theme settings and if I've understood correctly, that approach would remove the title from all my action bars.

How can I do this?

---

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this kind of simple stuff you just have to go to the source to find the answer:
here the full explanation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

and here some guide code, to include the spinner on the action bar:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

after that is just put a listener for the changes and setting the a spinner adapter.

and you can use:

```
 setTitle("");
```

to remove the title.
I've been checking on my codes here, you can also give a try on:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

It should just remove the title, and leave the title bar. Remember that you must call this before `setContentView`

happy coding.

Comment: Hi Budius. That's what I've done in my code. It shows me the dropdown but it also shows me the application name. I would only like the dropdown/spinner.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to explain better.

Comment: That's very weird cause I just finished an app with NAVIGATION_MODE_TAB and it removed, i was expecting the same behavior. You can try to `setTitle("");`

Comment: `setTitle("")` did it but I'm wondering if this is a correct way of accomplishing this. Could you edit your answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla hi.. I just edited and even suggested something else that looks more "proper way", I'm not sure if it works but it's an easy test.

Answer (score 12):

Can be done with a nice one liner

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

this will hide just the title. If you also want to hide the home logo

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

When using the AppCompat Support library, you should replace `getActionBar()` with `getSupportActionBar()`. It is also suggested that you check if the ActionBar is null before changing values on it.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar()
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: @Drdavidpier depends on state. Look into the Android Lifecycle. there are states in which the actionbar isn't created yet

Answer (score 1):

The above proposed solutions still show the title for a brief moment before making it invisible. I use the following which I believe is the best way to achieve this:

Simple disable app_name in the activity declaration in the Manifest. This way it will never show for the activity where you don't want it to appear:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" > <!-- Delete this -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -4):

use this in your activity tag of menifeast

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```