# Remove title from action bar activity

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity

I know how to remove the title in action bar activity from the code, but is it possible to remove the title from the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in [How do you remove the title text from the Android ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655874/how-do-you-remove-the-title-text-from-the-android-actionbar)

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppBaseTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. just set the title attribute for that activity to be empty in the Manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

By remove I assume you mean have an empty String value placed there? You can do it from the AndroidManifest.

When defining the activity in the manifest set "android:title" for the activities you want to remove the title in the action bar activity for.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:title=""/>
```