# Android - How to remove app name from ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is my app:

[image]

Now i want to remove the app name from my ActionBar...
I want it like this:

[image]

my code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:title="@string/phone"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/computer"
        android:title="@string/computer"
        android:icon="@drawable/computer"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />


</menu>
```

Comment: u might have defined label for activity in manifest.remove that and retry

Comment: i tryed... but it puts this name: com.example.development.actionbar

Comment: then "" add only this or setTitle() method in activity

Comment: Simply use the latest AppCompat. v21+.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove the title text from the Android ActionBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655874/how-do-you-remove-the-title-text-from-the-android-actionbar)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Or you can just call `actionbar.setTitle("")`

Comment: setTitle("") makes the title under launcher icon empty too. So the first strategy is better.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to hide it use this code

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

or if you want to change the name use this

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("type yor title here");
```

Answer (score 4):

I've seen some questions about the location etc. Here is the complete solution. Use this in onCreate();

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Set title to false AFTER toolbar has been set
    try
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call [setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29) and [setDisplayShowTitleEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled%28boolean%29) on ActionBar, which you get via a call to getActionBar().

Answer (score 2):

For Android 4.2.1 edit the default theme NoActionnBar and add this code in MainActivity.java file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `setTitle("")`. If you are using `ActionBar` or `ToolBar`, then call `bar.setTitle("")` or :

```
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```